# Release APK Crash in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

flutter run --release -->>

Flutter run key commands.
h Repeat this help message.
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).
E/AndroidRuntime(14424): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(14424): Process: com.gioexchange.app, PID: 14424
E/AndroidRuntime(14424): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lio/flutter/plugins/imagepicker/ImagePickerPlugin$LifeCycleObserver;
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin.c(Unknown Source:22)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin.d(Unknown Source:27)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.c.h(Unknown Source:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(Unknown Source:71)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at com.gioexchange.app.MainActivity.k(Unknown Source:5)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at io.flutter.embedding.android.i.k(Unknown Source:10)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at io.flutter.embedding.android.e.k(Unknown Source:58)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at io.flutter.embedding.android.i.u0(Unknown Source:10)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.Z0(Unknown Source:21)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at androidx.fragment.app.j.R0(Unknown Source:433)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at androidx.fragment.app.o.b(Unknown Source:206)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at androidx.fragment.app.o.c(Unknown Source:18)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at androidx.fragment.app.o.C(Unknown Source:36)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at androidx.fragment.app.j.n0(Unknown Source:110)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at androidx.fragment.app.j.Z0(Unknown Source:88)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at androidx.fragment.app.j.l0(Unknown Source:21)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at androidx.fragment.app.j.e0(Unknown Source:9)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at androidx.fragment.app.j.y(Unknown Source:6)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at androidx.fragment.app.f.c(Unknown Source:4)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at androidx.fragment.app.d.onStart(Unknown Source:15)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1334)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7033)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2793)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2905)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1606)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:169)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6595)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin$LifeCycleObserver
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        ... 32 more
E/AndroidRuntime(14424): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Interface androidx.lifecycle.b implemented by class io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin$LifeCycleObserver is inaccessible (declaration of 'io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin$LifeCycleObserver' appears in /data/app/com.gioexchange.app-m19xWFnw-h0Vo8t5Dxn8tw==/base.apk)
E/AndroidRuntime(14424):        ... 32 more

Comment: what Gradle version are you using?

Comment: @MaadhavSharma Gradle version 1.4.30

Comment: try this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58479#issuecomment-647827484

Comment: Unsupported Android Plugin version: 3.6.2.

Comment: Maybe try this : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58479#issuecomment-734099445

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a couple of things mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58247)

1. Add `lintOptions` to `app/build.gradle`

```
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
```

If this still doesn't work then

2. check the gradle version in `app/build.gradle` I was using 4.0.0 so I downgraded it to 3.6.2

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'
```

3. Lastly another alternative would be to add this plugin [flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle: ^2.0.1](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle) to your `pubspec.yaml` file .

Then rebuild the project and build the release apk.